# Android upload an file from Desktop PC to Android device

Tags: android-networking

I want my Android device to act as a HTTP server. When I start my server on my device it should show an IP address. When I access this device's IP address through my desktop PC (same network), I should be able to upload files from my desktop to the Android device.

I've tried *NanoHttpd.java* but it's hard to use and I want to use the same for downloading files as well. Is there any better solution to achieve these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NanoHTTPD` is good for handling file uploads and downloads. If you want to download files use the `serveFile` method by extending and overriding the `serve` method. In order to handle uploads, check for a `POST` request and get the file from `files` parameter. You'll get a temporary path where the uploaded file is placed. Use a `FileInputStream` to read the file and do whatever you want. Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

you also use the [Google Usb](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) driver

Comment: Hi Mike, I think you misunderstood the question, my requirement is make an android device has an server, when i open the ip of the device   anywhere on PC, there i have option to upload an file to android device, so the android device acts has an server.

Answer (score 0):

Use a software like AndSMB or some other SMB Client.
regards,

Comment: thanks for your response,can you please check NanoHttp just a single with few lines of code only..